# Salesforce DX Question (deploy profiles)

Tags: salesforcedx, cli

Anyone who already tried the new Salesforce CLI to transfer Metadata from one org to another?

Is it possible to transfer Profiles?

I already tried to search for a guide but I wasn't able to find one.

Anyone who has the exact steps or an article?

Any help or info is much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the orgs are connected , a better option is to use change set since you can easily detect dependencies and add them .

Using sfdx you can use `sfdx force:source:retrieve` to accomplish [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) .

To retrieve profile you can use below .This also shows how to retrieve apex class and custom object along as well

```
$ sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "ApexClass, Profile:My Profile, Profile: AnotherProfile,CustomObject:Object1"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using sfdx source commands. If you are familiar with pushing profiles with ANT it will be easy for you. Please note to get the full metadata about profiles you need to mention the related data as well. for example to get the profile access related details for an object that object must be present with the profile in same package.

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_pull) You will get all the source related commands in CLI. ou need to use sfdx force:source:pull followed by an sfdx force:source:push with required parameters. Please let us know if this helps or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Avijiit I would also want to use ANT but our IT is restricting me from installing any compiler like Eclipse. Do you suggest to Deploy profile using CLI or just Manual? Thanks again